# failed to add routing entry using CreateIpForwardEntry

Tags: winapi, networking, routes

I have Wireguard VPN on my machine, which add its route entry to metric 5 with destination 0.0.0.0. And my default entry is at metric 25 with 0.0.0.0.

When I try to add a routing table entry with metric less than 5 using `CreateIpForwardEntry()`, it fails with error 1168.

What could be the problem? Is it conflicting with the default routing entry?

Below is my code:

```
PMIB_IPFORWARDTABLE pIpForwardTable = NULL;
PMIB_IPFORWARDROW pRow = NULL;
DWORD dwSize = 0;
BOOL bOrder = FALSE;
DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    
unsigned int i;

dwStatus = GetIpForwardTable(pIpForwardTable, &dwSize, bOrder);
if (dwStatus == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
    // Allocate the memory for the table
    if (!(pIpForwardTable = (PMIB_IPFORWARDTABLE) malloc(dwSize))) {
        printf("Malloc failed. Out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Now get the table.
    dwStatus = GetIpForwardTable(pIpForwardTable, &dwSize, bOrder);
}
// Search for the row in the table we want. The default gateway has a destination
// of 0.0.0.0.
for (i = 0; i < pIpForwardTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
    if (pIpForwardTable->table[i].dwForwardDest == 0) {
        // We have found the default gateway.
        if (!pRow) {
            pRow = (PMIB_IPFORWARDROW) malloc(sizeof (MIB_IPFORWARDROW));
            memcpy(pRow, &(pIpForwardTable->table[i]),
                sizeof (MIB_IPFORWARDROW));
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Set the nexthop field to our new gateway - all the other properties of the route will
// be the same as they were previously.
pRow->dwForwardMask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
pRow->dwForwardDest = 0x14cf4952;
pRow->dwForwardProto = MIB_IPPROTO_NETMGMT;
pRow->dwForwardIfIndex = 0x12;
pRow->dwForwardMetric1 = 0x4;

dwStatus = CreateIpForwardEntry(pRow);
printf("Error: %d\n", dwStatus);

exit(0);
```

Comment: I suggest you could try to use `FormatMessage` to obtain the message string for the returned error.